# Parsing text from webpage with Kanna

Tags: swift, html-parsing

First of all I am a new to Swift and general programming. I am trying to do my best to improve myself. I have checked many questions related my problem here yet I fail whatever I do. What I am trying to do is to parse some text on a web page with XPath using Kanna. The thing is I manage to do so on Wikipedia but when I try it on another site it does not work. My code is below. Do you have any ideas what I do wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yazi: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (URL(string: "http://uk.investing.com/currencies/usd-gbp")!), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            for link in doc.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/section/h2[1]/a") {
                print(link.text)
                yazi.text = link.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Does the application crash? Does it just give you back `nil` or an empty `String`? Explain in more detail, and post the error logs if applicable.

Comment: I think this is the error I get from the console: 2016-09-28 00:02:45.744 Banka[4588:228651] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2016-09-28 00:02:45.822775 Banka[4588:228409] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence

Comment: OK. I did some research and found out the page I parse text from must use https protocol. I have changed the site and the code regarding so but right now I get no error on console. It is completely empty. http://imgur.com/a/PmAK1

Comment: Instead of posting comments, you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39733076/edit). Also, you should copy and paste any code, don't use a screenshot unless you specifically need to show something within Xcode itself.

Comment: As for the parser returning empty; I am unfamiliar with Kanna and the library it is based on, Nokogiri, but could it be that your `xpath` is incorrect? Kanna does not have much documentation; but based on the documentation for [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) and some of the source code, should the `xpath` not be more like: `doc.css("div:nth-child(3)").css("h2:nth-child(1)").xpath("//a")`? If that does not work, maybe start with a simpler `xpath`? You can also post an example of your HTML, maybe that will help.